# Getting duplicated cardviews using SwipeRefresh Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

So here is my problem, I got an API that gives me the lastest news of many sources. Each one of them goes with a `cardview`. The problem here is, while I'm using the `swipeRefresh`, it gets duplicated `cardViews` with the same news, like if I have 10 news, it duplicates to 20 with the same ones.
Here is my code where I apply the `swipeRefresh`:

```
package com.example.newsapp4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.newsapp4.Model.Articles;
import com.example.newsapp4.Model.Headlines;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class bbcnews extends AppCompatActivity {
    Adapter adapter;
    Intent intencion;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public static String source = "My Source";
    public static String API_KEY = "My API Key";
    SwipeRefreshLayout srl;

    List<Articles> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bbcnews);

        srl = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        srl.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                retrieveJson(source, API_KEY);
            }
        });


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        adapter = new Adapter(bbcnews.this,articles);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        retrieveJson(source, API_KEY);

    }

    public void retrieveJson(String source, String apiKey){

        srl.setRefreshing(true);
        Call<Headlines> call = ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().getHeadlines(source, apiKey);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Headlines>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Headlines> call, Response<Headlines> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getArticles() != null){
                    srl.setRefreshing(false);
                    articles.clear();
                    articles = response.body().getArticles();
                    adapter.setArticles(articles);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Headlines> call, Throwable t) {
                srl.setRefreshing(false);
                Toast.makeText(bbcnews.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public String getCountry(){
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        String country = locale.getCountry();
        return country.toLowerCase();

    }

    public void aPerfil(View vista){
        intencion = new Intent(this, profile_activity.class);
        startActivity(intencion);
    }
}
```

I don't think that I need to put the xml code with the `progressbar` and the `swipeRefresh` but here are both:

This one is the `Items.xml` where I created the `cardView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/loader"/>


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/img"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TITLE"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/g_bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Source"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:ems="15"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/g_light"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:id="@+id/tvSource"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/g_light"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tvDate"/>




            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
```

And here the one with the `swipeRefresh` in the `recyclerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".bbcnews">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DINGO BBC NEWS"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/g_bold"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>



    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/black_background"
        android:rowCount="2">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@drawable/black_background"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/black_background"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"/>

    </GridLayout>


    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"/>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Also this is my `adapter.java` code:

```
package com.example.newsapp4;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.newsapp4.Model.Articles;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<Articles> articles;

    public Adapter(Context context, List<Articles> articles) {
        this.context = context;
        this.articles = articles;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Articles a = articles.get(position);

        String imageUrl = a.getUrlToImage();

        holder.tvTitle.setText(a.getTitle());
        holder.tvSource.setText(a.getSource().getName());
        holder.tvDate.setText(a.getPublishedAt());


        Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvTitle,tvSource,tvDate;
        ImageView imageView;
        CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvSource = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSource);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        }
    }

    public void setArticles(List<Articles> articles) {
        this.articles.addAll(articles);
        int count = getItemCount();
        notifyItemRangeInserted(count, count + articles.size());
    }


}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Could you add code for your Adapter for reference?

Comment: Done, I updated the section.

Comment: What is your exact requirement when you refresh whether you need to replace all the previous data with new data or compare existing and new data and add only those which are not present?

Comment: My exact requirement is that when I refresh the data, it will appear new data, replacing the old one, but in this case, I have news that are important so even if I refresh it will appear there. I just wanted to show for example 10 news, even if I refresh and still the same, but Im getting 20 of them, maybe a couple different but 20 not 10 as my API says, because many API links has an amount of news to show like 10 or even 100. Hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   // Clear adapter list before add to list.

  public void setArticles(List<Articles> articles) {
        
                   if(this.articles!=null && this.articles.size()>0)
                      this.articles.clear();
        
                this.articles.addAll(articles);
                int count = getItemCount();
                notifyItemRangeInserted(count, count + articles.size());
            }
```

Comment: It really worked for me with this simple code, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand in your code is on the success of API call after Swipe Refresh which is this section here

```java
articles.clear();
articles = response.body().getArticles();
adapter.setArticles(articles);
```

You are here clearing the article inside your activity, but the thing is inside your Adapter there is already another list of articles, you are not clearing them.

And then when you make the `adapter.setArticles(articles);` call, inside the following function, your articles get added to the already existing list of articles and thus, the duplicate list.

```java
public void setArticles(List<Articles> articles) {
        this.articles.addAll(articles);
        int count = getItemCount();
        notifyItemRangeInserted(count, count + articles.size());
    }
```

To fix this you can make the following modifications to your function.

```java
public void setArticles(List<Articles> articles, boolean clearAll) {
        if(clearAll){ this.articles.clear(); }
        this.articles.addAll(articles);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And then modify your function call as follows

```java
adapter.setArticles(articles, true);
```

That way when the Boolean is true, it will clear the existing list. Also I would suggest you to replace the insert call with data set change call. Else you can make a separate function all together for adding elements and for clearing existing elements.